# ffmpeg fast but accurate seek in avi

Tags: ffmpeg

I've built a small pipeline to automatically cut and enhance video files which I recorded.

I detect scenes by using the ffmpeg's `select='gt(scene,0.4)',showinfo` filter. After parsing these information I run `ffmpeg` for each scene to produce single video files for them, for example:

```
ffmpeg -y -i test.avi -ss 00:00:00.00 -to 00:00:54.61 -c copy test_1.avi
ffmpeg -y -i test.avi -ss 00:00:54.61 -to 00:01:38.21 -c copy test_2.avi
ffmpeg -y -i test.avi -ss 00:01:38.21 -to 00:01:59.45 -c copy test_3.avi
[...]
```

As you can see I use the `-ss` and `-to` parameters to specify where the output files should start and end. This is working very well **but** it becomes very, very slow over time since my original file size is ~50 gigabytes.

I guess that `-ss` lets ffmpeg seek from the beginning of the original file to the start time as I can observe disk action when seeking.

Placing the `-ss` param before the `-i` input file is faster **but** very inaccurate (off by some seconds).

Is there maybe any trick to increase the cut/trim performance without losing the accuracy?

I also tried to convert the input file to MP4 which decreases the file size and seek time significantly. But then I had keyframe errors and I want to operate on the original files.

Thank you!

Comment: I have the same question. It should clearly be possible to do a fast seek to the appropriate keyframe first, then slow seek to the frame. No?